# Excel 2016 Chart Axis-X not showing the correctly

Tags: excel, excel-2016, excel-charts

I have a Excel file (.xlsm type) contains lot of Charts. After switch to Excel 2016, certain charts not showing Label correctly (axis-x).
Eg. It suppose showing WK10'17, WK11'17, WK12'17,...
but it showing 1,2,3,4,....

1) I tried to reselect the data, then the label showing correctly, but after save and reopen, it become 1,2,3,4.... again

2) also tried delete the existing chart, and create a new one in Excel 2010 & 2016, problem not solve.

3) Axis Type have been set as Text

Is this a bug in Excel 2016 ? Did anyone have a solution for this ?

Below Chart showing 1,2,3,4,..., which is wrong.
[image]

Below chart is showing correctly.

[image]

Below are my table look like
[image]

**1st Experiment:**

Firstly, I create a whole new file in Excel 2016. Then do below step:
- Create 4 Indicators for performance review, with dummy data
- Create new chart and format it
- Create simple VBA code to hide everything, and only show related Indicator that selected

Everything work just fine, even switching around the indicator many times.
Later, Close it and reopen, 3 out of 4 charts having Axis-x label became 1,2,3,...

**2nd Experiment:**

I created Whole new file in Excel 2010, with 4 indicators and same VBA code.
Then Close and reopen, Axis-x format remain Perfectly good.
Transfer the file into Excel 2016 machine. Close and reopen, the Axis-x became 1,2,3....

*** Current Excel Version 1705 (Build 8201.2075)

*** Attach with these experiment files
[4Q Demo.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8Nwt2ZUDPSzLWRud0FIOHhWc0k)

Appreciate, who got interested into this issue, have a look on my file.
Share with me, if you do have any solution for that. Thanks

Comment: What version of Excel were the charts created in? There have been changes in the charting engine in recent versions.  Excel 2013 and later have a different way to show combination charts (like column and line) and you may need to re-define the X axis values. This should be an easy task if you are using VBA. Just record creating a combo chart with XL 2016 and apply the respective changes to your VBA. Get with the programme. Don't just sit there and complain that it does not work anymore.

Comment: i have recreated the chart in 2010 and 2016, not solving the problem. btw I'm posting a question not complaint.

Comment: Question vs complaint: Fair enough. Understood. What are the settings for the X axis in the 2016 version? If you record creating such a chart in 2010 and again in 2016, how does the code compare? Do you see ANY differences to the 2010 code?

Comment: the chart create manually not VBA. basically chart will not delete, the data in range of cell will update(as per above attach). I duplicate the file into 2 machines having 2010 and 2016, then delete several chart then create new one, then save and close. when open file the chart axis x will turn to 1,2,3...

Comment: Maybe you did not understand what I'm driving at:  In order to work out what you need to change in the code, use the macro recorder and create a combination column/line chart in 2010. Then use the macro recorder and create the same chart in 2016. Compare the two resulting macros. Do you see differences in the code? That should be your starting point for adjusting the macros for 2016. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: i will try your method. need to highlight here, there have no macro deal with the chart. that the reason i didn't tag VBA for this question.

Comment: Why then does your question start with `I have a macro contains lot of Charts`. If you don't use VBA, what do you mean with that?

Comment: ya it's xlsm file with coding, but the code didn't touch the chart data range nor formatting chart

Answer (score 0):

I found out as long as the Chart is not hide, then the axis-x will remain correctly. But this do not really help, when hiding additional chart is a must.

Another temporary workaround method is :

1) moving the data table to another worksheet.

2) Then the set the Chart's data range to another worksheet (Cannot be the same worksheet with Chart).

That will work perfectly, now can hide the chart while maintain axis-x correctly.

**** Only drawback, table have to move or duplicate into another worksheet

**** Probably Microsoft will solve this after Version 1705 (Build 8201.2075)